# How do I alter the items in my DropDownList in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, databound

I have this that gets bound in my code behind:

```
 <asp:DropDownList id="ddlPopulation" runat="server" DataTextField="population" DataValueField="pid" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
<asp:ListItem>Default</asp:ListItem>
```

How do I alter the list items in the code behind? I want to do an Html_Decode and Trim on them before they are rendered to the user?

The DataBind code is:

```
 StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

    // Define sql
    sql.Append("SELECT DISTINCT datasource ");
    sql.Append("FROM meta ");
    sql.Append("WHERE datasource != '' ");
    sql.Append("ORDER BY datasource ASC ");

    IDataReader reader = SqlHelper.GetDataReader(sql.ToString());

    ddlDatasources.DataSource = reader;
    ddlDatasources.DataBind();
```

Comment: What's with the kooky stringbuilder usage?  You're not gaining anything there, you should just use a string and not concatenate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can subscribe to the DataBound event of the DropDownList and do something like the following:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlPopulation" runat="server" DataTextField="population" DataValueField="pid" AppendDataBoundItems="True" OnDataBound="ddlPopulation_DataBound">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

and

```
protected void ddlPopulation_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  foreach(ListItem Item in ddlPopulation.Items){
    Item.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(Item.Text.Trim());
  }
}
```

Comment: It is unfortunate that the DropDownList does not have an ItemDataBound event

Comment: No overload for 'Population_DataBound' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler' what is this?

Comment: Added markup definition for control and made the event handler protected.  Not sure why you are getting that error.  If you continue to get it could you post what your modified code looks like?

Comment: yeah now i get your above comment